# NPM commands 'Aborted' if I don't run as root.

Tags: node.js, npm

I've run into what I think is a fairly new problem - I'm running npm on my production machine and it only runs when I'm logged in as `root`. Otherwise, it just exits saying "Aborted". The only command I can give is `npm -v` which prints out `4.2.0`

It seems like a permissions issue (one answer for which was to delete and re-install everything with NVM) but I hadn't seen anyone else reporting this issue of the command just exiting with "Aborted", so I wanted to see if there was something else going on before doing anything drastic.

Let me know if I can provide any additional context! Thanks, all!

Comment: which OS ? try using `sudo <command>`

Comment: npm should not need sudo except for global installs. Let's start with "how did you install node"? If you're on OSX, use `brew` to install the latest version, if you're on Windows, grab the installer from nodejs.org, if you're in linux, you should already know what to do.

Comment: I'm on Linux. I don't actually remember how I installed npm unfortunately.

Comment: uninstall it, and install the latest Node instead following the recommended installation procedure for your version of linux explained over on https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/ (comes with the latest npm, don't install that separately). Node 4 was in maintenance-only mode for a while but as of last week literally got killed off as "no longer maintained in any way". The latest LTS is v8, the latest stable is v9

Comment: Thanks. To clarify, the NPM version is 4.2.0, but the Node version is 7.10.1.

Comment: still worth uninstalling, and installing the officially endorsed way first, so you're on node 9.11 with npm 5.6 - because simply updating to the current npm may very well resolve your problem entirely.